# User Timezone Issue Fix in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, timezone

I am developing a php application in which i need to detect the user timzone(from where they are accessing the application). I have tried with the JavaScript time zone detection method and the problem what I am facing if the user has changed the timezone or machine time which will affect my calculation.

I want to avoid the dependency to the system time. Please give suggestions for any alternative method for this.

Thank you.

Comment: Well, what method would you have us choose, then? How are we to reliably determine the location of a user if their own system does not provide accurate information? Triangulate their IP address by building a GUI in visual basic and enhancing?

Comment: The client has to report its timezone to the server, or better yet, it's current time. You cannot "detect" their time without it telling you, as far as I know.

Comment: If you go with IP address detection, be sure to ask the user if that is their timezone before setting it, as IPs aren't very reliable. If they indicate that it isn't their timezone give them a dropdown to choose the correct timezone.

Answer (score 2):

I have done this before using the DB11 database from IP2Location which will allow you to find a users timezone based on their ip address. They have a free version that you can test with but it is not as accurate as the paid version. You can download it from https://lite.ip2location.com/database-ip-country-region-city-latitude-longitude-zipcode-timezone and it includes instructions on that page for setting it up depending on what type of database you are using.

Assuming you are using MySQL with php, here is some sample code to help you get started once you have the database set up. At the very least you will have to change the $ServerName, $DbLogin and $DbPassword variables to your own setup to get a proper connection to the database:

```
<?
/* function to convert ip address in x.x.x.x format to integer/long for use with the ip2location database */

function convertIpToLong($ip) {
    return sprintf("%u", ip2long($ip));
}

$ServerName = "localhost";  // change to real mysql ip
$DatabaseName = "ip2location";
$DbLogin = "root";      // change to a db user that has read permission to your new database
$DbPassword = "password";   // change to your db user password

$link = mysqli_connect($ServerName, $DbLogin, $DbPassword);

// connect to database

mysqli_select_db($link, $DatabaseName)
    or die("Could not select database");

$ipAddress = convertIpToLong('8.8.8.8');    // change to real ip address here
$query = "SELECT * FROM ip2location_db11 WHERE ".$ipAddress." >= ip_from AND ".$ipAddress." <= ip_to;";

// test if the ip address is matched to one in the database

if (mysqli_multi_query($link, $query)) {
    $result = mysqli_store_result($link);   // found a match
}
else {
    die("Query failed : " . mysqli_error($link));
}

$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result); // load results into row variable
mysqli_free_result($result);    // clear resultset

// write each column to the screen

foreach ($row as $key => $val) {
    echo $key." = ".$val."<br />";
}
?>
```